# Lambda function mutable keyword

Tags: c++

Why does the code below not work, but works if I capture the variables by reference?

In .hpp, I have declared the `x` and `y` variables.

A.hpp:

```
int x;
int y;
```

A.cpp:

```
f([&]() {x=10; y=12;}` // it works
```

But this doesn't work:

```
f([this]) mutable { x=10; y=12;}
```

I want to capture `x` by value.

Comment: There is no `class` or `struct` in your code here.  What do you want `this` to refer to?

Comment: This question's shown code fails to meet Stackoverflow's requirements for showing a [mre]. Because of that it's unlikely that anyone here can conclusively answer the question; but only guess at the most. You need to [edit] your question to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that everyone else can cut/paste ***exactly as shown***, compile, run, and reproduce the described issue (the "reproducible" part, this includes any ancillary information, like any input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Answer (score 2):

> I wan't to capture x by value;

You can capture x by value like this:

```
[x]{}
```

Comment: You can also capture everything by value using `[=]`. This is the closest equivalent to `[&]` but for values, not references.